# `container_memory_working_set_bytes` - How to interpret value at same time for same container but with different names?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, cadvisor

```
2023-12-07 09:47:00.000 container_memory_working_set_bytes{
    container="my-app", 
    endpoint="https-metrics", 
    id="/kubepods/burstable/podb7ecf824-6797-4183-9566-434142df3757/e5c6aec2cc6cf7abbd2163cd195b181954df28fc134478e2cfd27283c2a7838f", 
    image="my-image", 
    instance="172.22.106.15:10250", 
    job="kubelet", 
    metrics_path="/metrics/cadvisor", 
    name="571e004d52fa4ed1c4b3eacef27feb844bfaf1d7e6b8bdbcdae1e35bce9f4b83", 
    namespace="my-app", 
    node="node2", 
    pod="web-5dfd4896b4-x4nsr"
}   915144704

2023-12-07 09:47:00.000 container_memory_working_set_bytes{
    container="my-app", 
    endpoint="https-metrics", 
    id="/kubepods/burstable/podb7ecf824-6797-4183-9566-434142df3757/fcce62cda4d8300c82f4552ddd069b59e8de30c31ece187a6349fe786f182e7a", 
    image="my-image", 
    instance="172.22.106.15:10250", 
    job="kubelet", 
    metrics_path="/metrics/cadvisor", 
    name="326d2a900bcbd9bd983e128e39b3391dcf37469dd863c19b222a834adc59400d", 
    namespace="my-app", 
    node="node2", 
    pod="web-5dfd4896b4-x4nsr"
}   799879168
```

Is the used memory the sum of these two: 915144704 + 799879168 ?

or the maximum of these two: max(915144704, 799879168) ?

related [google/cadvisor - Duplicated metrics for restarted Pods](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/issues/2844#issue-853627821)

Comment: Can you check if metric `up` is available there? and if it's 0 for `_7`?

Comment: You mean if `up` key is part of `container_memory_working_set_bytes`, right? If so, then no, `container_memory_working_set_bytes` has no `up` key. Can you maybe link what it does? Maybe I can check if I can enable it then...

Comment: I meant metric `up`. Like [this](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=up&g0.tab=1&g0.stacked=0&g0.show_exemplars=0&g0.range_input=1h). I'm not sure if cadvisor exposes this for pods.

Answer (score 1):

Based on provided issue (specifically graphs in it) looks like (a not so correct behaviour of) [the staleness](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#staleness) is at play.

Most likely former metric (with name ending in `_7` in your case) is simply a leftovers, and should be ignored. And correct size of memory used is simply `799879168` (value of the latter metric).

I'm not familiar with cadvisor enough to explain this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I should have used real names, as the suffixes `_7` and `_8` are just put in as an example, real names are indistinguishable hashes. I updated the answer accordingly. **So in such a case we actual can not query the latter metric, cause we don't know which if the former and which is the latter, right?**

Comment: @goulashsoup, in reality you cannot query them (adequately) even if they were named like `_7` and `_8`.

Comment: So I guess the best I can do is use `max` of these values for monitoring memory usage, right?

Comment: If `up` is absent - then I think so. If `up` is present, you can probably use some workarounds to get a correct value.

Comment: `up` is present, but is `1` for all values I can associate with given `container_memory_working_set_bytes` at the time `2023-12-07 09:47:00.000`, also not sure how you think the `up` value can be associated with one of the two reported `container_memory_working_set_bytes` metrics, as I can only match both via `up.instance` and `up.node`, but both `container_memory_working_set_bytes` have the same `instance` and `node`?

Comment: Ah, so up is provided only for server, not each pod. Then it cannot be used. Sorry for misleading, as I said I'm not very familiar with cadvisor.